# How can I open an Expo App using URL in Detox?

Tags: react-native, expo, detox

I want to open an app with URL in Detox tests.
I followed this [`openApp.js`](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/e2e-tests/) from [Expo guide](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/e2e-tests/) to open the app in Detox.

However, the guide doesn't tell me how to open an app using URL; for example, `myapp://some/path`.

More precisely, I want to know how to add `some/path` in the following url scheme.

```js
const getDevLauncherPackagerUrl = platform =>
  `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=${platform}&dev=true&minify=false&disableOnboarding=1`;
```

I could not find a satisfying answer in the official document.

(I tried putting `url` param, but it did not work.)